# rvest webscraping with placeholder counts that update daily

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to scrape global daily counts of cases and deaths from JHU: https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/

[It seems that the counts are stored like this when I use the web inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE3Ly.png) but when I try to use the following code to access them, all I can find are placeholders:

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/"
website = read_html(url)

cases <- website %>%
  html_nodes(css = "figure")

cases
```

produces the following:

```
{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <figure><figcaption>Global Confirmed</figcaption><p class="FeaturedStats_stat-placeholder__1Dax8">Loading...</p></figure>
[2] <figure><figcaption>Global Deaths</figcaption><p class="FeaturedStats_stat-placeholder__1Dax8">Loading...</p></figure>
[3] <figure><figcaption>U.S. Confirmed</figcaption><p class="FeaturedStats_stat-placeholder__1Dax8">Loading...</p></figure>
[4] <figure><figcaption>U.S. Deaths</figcaption><p class="FeaturedStats_stat-placeholder__1Dax8">Loading...</p></figure>
```

So I can access these, but all that's stored in them is "Loading..." where the actual count appears on the site and in the webinspect. I'm new to this so I appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you!

Comment: I guess, the data is created/loaded via JavaScript or something like that. Perhaps `RSelenium` could help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you're interested in are updated by querying another source, so the page loads initially with the "Loading..." that you're seeing. You can see this in action if you refresh the page - initially, there's only "Loading..." in the boxes that's later filled in. The trick here is to find the source that supplies that information and request *that*, rather than the page itself. Here, the page that https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/ pulls from is https://jhucoronavirus.azureedge.net/jhucoronavirus/homepage-featured-stats.json, so we can query that directly.

```
url <- "https://jhucoronavirus.azureedge.net/jhucoronavirus/homepage-featured-stats.json"
website = read_html(url)

website %>%
  html_element(xpath = "//p") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

returning a neat data frame of

```
     generated      updated cases.global cases.US deaths.global deaths.US
1 1.637691e+12 1.637688e+12    258453277 47902038       5162675    772588
```

You were off to a good start by using the web inspect, but finding sources is a little trickier and usually requires using Chrome's "Network" tab instead of the default "Elements". In this case, I was able to find the source by slowing down the request speed (enabling throttling to "Slow 3G") and then watching for network activity that occurred after the initial page load. The only major update came from the URL I've suggested above:

[image]

(green bar in the top left was the original page loading, second lower green bar currently highlighted with a blue aura was the next major update)

which I could then access directly in Chrome (copy/paste URL) to see the raw JSON.

As an additional note, because you're webscraping I'd recommend [the `polite` package](https://github.com/dmi3kno/polite) to obey the website's rules for scraping which I've included below:

```
  robots.txt: 1 rules are defined for 1 bots
  Crawl delay: 5 sec
  The path is scrapable for this user-agent
```