# R: Errors when webscraping across mulitple tables with same URL

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to webscraping and having issues troubleshooting my code. At the moment I'm having different errors every time and don't really know where to continue. Currently looking into utilizing RSelenium but would greatly appreciate some advise and feedback on the code below.

Based my initial code on the following: [R: How to web scrape a table across multiple pages with the same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590600/r-how-to-web-scrape-a-table-across-multiple-pages-with-the-same-url)

```
library(xml2)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

i=1
table = list()
for (i in 1:15) {
  data=("https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/no/salg-av-eiendom/solgte-eiendommer/","?page=",i))
  page <- read_html(data)
  table1 <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "(//table)[2]") %>%
    html_table(header=T)
  i=i+1
  table1[[1]][[7]]=as.integer(gsub(",", "",table1[[1]][[7]]))
  table=bind_rows(table, table1)
  print(i)}

table$`ÅR`=as.Date(table$`ÅR`,format ="%Y")
```

Bellow are the errors i am recieving at the moment. I know its a lot, but i assume some of them are a result of previous errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

i=1

> table = list()
> for (i in 1:15) {

- data=("https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/no/salg-av-eiendom/solgte-eiendommer/","?page=",i))

Error: unexpected ',' in:
"for (i in 1:15) {
data=("https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/no/salg-av-eiendom/solgte-eiendommer/","

> page <- read_html(data)

Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :
no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "function"

> table1 <- page %>%

- ```
  html_nodes(xpath = "(//table)[2]") %>%
  ```
- ```
  html_table(header=T)
  ```

Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function"

> i=i+1
> table1[[1]][[7]]=as.integer(gsub(",", "",table1[[1]][[7]]))

Error in is.factor(x) : object 'table1' not found

> table=bind_rows(table, table1)

Error in list2(...) : object 'table1' not found

> print(i)}

Error: unexpected '}' in "  print(i)}"

> table$`ÃR`=as.Date(table$`ÃR`,format ="%Y")

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Have added the errors i am recieving above. Assume some of the are results of previous errors. Some tips on which parts to work on first would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use api `fromJSON('https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/ListApi/ListContent/78635/SoldEstates/0/1402/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces a dataframe containing all the data you are seeking.  Rather than using RSelenium, the below code fetches the data directly from the same API from which the site populates the table and so you do not need to combine multiple pages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

####GET NUMBER OF ITEMS#####

url <- "https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/ListApi/ListContent/78635/SoldEstates/0/10/"

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url, flatten = TRUE)

totalItems <- data$TotalNumberOfItems

####GET ALL OF THE ITEMS#####

allData <- paste0('https://www.forsvarsbygg.no/ListApi/ListContent/78635/SoldEstates/0/', totalItems,'/') %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON(., flatten = TRUE) %>%
  .[1] %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "ListItems.", ""), everything())
```

Comment: This was a great way to fetch the data! Can i ask how you went about assessing if this was feasable for the site? How would i check this for another site for example?

Comment: Hi Einar -- Trial and error. One typically (1) checks the network tab when inspecting a website to try to identify the sources from which the page is extracting information and (2) tailors the query to whatever parameters the source requires.  

An example of the process is here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084895/rvest-webscraping-with-placeholder-counts-that-update-daily/70086271#70086271

Comment: Thank you again, really appreciate it!